# Performance issue with too many css files in rails 4 app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, performance

I am building an app in Rails 4 and am using asset pipeline. For my workflow, I've split my css into 10+ separate sheets.  Should I combine them for deployment or does it not matter as long as they're minified?  I'm wondering how much performance will be affected with separate stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

The default behavior is to combine your CSS files for you in production, into one asset with a hash on the end to make sure it updates when you change the files.

For example, here is my company's css file:

http://quickleft.com/assets/application-ff836a79f9021feeab313402499df444.css

but in our `assets/stylesheets` folder we have 20+ individual files to keep ourselves organized.

Combining and minifying your CSS *is* important though, as it can significantly reduce the bytes needed to be sent over the wire to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article out on bundling: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification. Even though the article is about bundling in .NET, the browser/performance related concerns are applicable.

In short, browsers can only get 6 resource files at a time so, even though you have your stylesheets minified making the file size smaller, performance will be affected because of the limit of files a browser will retrieve at one time.